# qt set widget width according to layout'width

Tags: c++, qt

I have three instances of `QWidget`, `WidgetMain` and `WidgetMerchandise` and `WidgetCentral`. `WidgetMain` has `BorderLayout`, implemented in [Border Layout Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-borderlayout-example.html). Now, `WidgetMerchandise` is on the west side of layout, `WidgetCentral` is set on Central side of layout.but I would like `WidgetMerchandise` to have width to 1/4 width of `WidgetCentral`. Do I have to reimplement `sizeHint()` and `minimumSizeHit()` or should I achieve this task using qt size policies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widget sizes within the same layout are controlled by **stretch factors**. You can call `setStretch` method of the layout, or your can directly set these factors in the designer mode:

[image]

The above picture shows the example of 3 widgets in one layout, and the default `layoutStrech` is **0,0,0** (it has the same effect as **1,1,1**). You may change it to **1,4,1** for example, so the left most widget will be 1/4 width of the second (central) widget. This is the case when horizontal layout is used, where the stretch factor determines the width. Otherwise, if vertical layout is used, the stretch factor represents the ratio of heights.

Comment: Tay2510, this is ok, but in `Qt` version `5.4.1` I cannot find method `setStretch` anywhere inside docs.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih In Qt 5 docs, the inherited members are hidden within the link :["List of all members, including inherited members"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhboxlayout-members.html)